# Wix ProgressDlg not showing status info properly

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

Am setting an installer for our application using **Wix**. Am using *WixUI_Mondo* dialog set. The problem is that *ProgressDlg* is displaying the status like this:

> Status: Copying new files: File: [1], Directory: [9], Size: [6]

What would be missing in my wxs file?

Thanks!

PS: Am not customizing anything in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this issue only appears with Windows 10 I was able to fix this by adding this element to my project wxs:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```